# Unity SOAP wsdl problem

Tags: unity

i'm trying to using a SOAP service from my game but the problem is that after using wsdl.exe for generete the connector Unity inform me that System.Web namespace doesn't exist.

How can I use the wsdl?
There is some workaround without writing a lot of code?

Many thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've been able to resolve my issue by importing these DLLs in my project:

- `System.Web.dll`
- `System.Web.Services.dll`